# Trigger jenkins job from Eclipse

Tags: jenkins, eclipse-plugin

I have a Jenkins instance available over the internet. I have some jobs which need to be triggered manually (server start/server down). I found this cloudbees plugin which is supposed to work with on-prem Jenkins instance. However, when configuring the plugin it does not work.

Using the URL `https://<jenkins_ur>/api/json` on browser works, but cloudbess plugin complains about breadcrumb not found when trying to configure from Eclipse.

Comment: Which CloudBees plug-in do you use? Could you share the error message? With the [Eclipse Mylyn Builds](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Builds) plug-in you can also trigger Jenkins jobs.

Comment: Here is the [eclipse plugin link](http://eclipse.cloudbees.com). I will try the Eclipse Mylyn Builds plugin.

Comment: I am not able to use the eclipse mylyn builds plugin. I dont see the option of team repository showing up in my eclipse. Is there something else I need to install for this to work?